# Trouble with spiral folding bike lock - jammed

Tags: lock

I use a spiral folding bike lock similiar to the one here: http://www.amazon.co.uk/RockBros-Theft-Folding-Hamburg-Colors/dp/B00MB7NUB6

It was a fairly decent lock, but now it's jammed; I've tried all of my spare keys and everything and the lock just refuses to budge.

Here's what happens when I insert the key and twist it: I am able to twist it fully as if I would open it, but then when I pull the key out, the locking mechanism refuses to pop out; it sort of just stays there when in fact it should release the lock.

I have no clue what to do to open it. I'm not sure if a hacksaw would work as this thing looks strong enough to take one and I have no clue how to fix the jam.

Here's a picture of the bike lock:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jiggle it, wiggle it, slap it around a little.  The latch part is probably not retracting when it should.   You can also blast the lock with a penetrating lubricant and repeat the jiggle/wiggle/tap.

You could try contacting Rock Bros at http://www.rockbrosbike.com/article-info.php?artid=6   for advice and possible replacement.

Its slightly disconcerting that their email addresses are given as 
rockbrosbike@gmail.com and rockbrosbike@hotmail.com

Is your bike locked up somewhere else?   I'd recommend you go and add more locks to it until this one is removed.  If you give up, use a grinder to cut the lock completely and throw it away.

Comment: +1 for penetrating lubricant, I use a tiny squirt of this stuff every 6 months when the mechanism gets stiff on my lock which is used outside. http://abuspadlocksonline.co.uk/abus-lock-lubricant.html

Comment: Interesting advice! The lock really isn't from Rock Bros, it just looks exactly like the one on their Amazon. Though, you're probably right, I should take some WD-40 and try lubricating. And yes, the latch part isn't retracting, that is exactly the problem. I will post updates...

Comment: If its a chinese knockoff...  well this is the sort of thing that happens.  I bet its got plain steel rather than stainless steel, I mean its all steel right?  Locks are something worth spending money on, because they last.

Comment: I would avoid the WD-40 and find a lock-specific lubricant, from a locksmith or hardware store.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I wouldn't care - the lock has proven itself as a failure.  My only goal would be to release the bike without damage to the bike, then biff the lock in the scrap.  A lock that doesn't work is like a helmet made of glass - not fit for purpose.

Comment: The thing is that you need a lube that will soak into the lock, and not leave a residue.  Not simply to preserve the lock for the future, but to get the stuck parts sliding.

Comment: I tried using WD-40 today; I sprayed some into the keyhole and voila! The damn thing opened like a charm. But now what's going to happen to the lock? Why the advice to avoid WD-40?

Comment: @ReiJinThunderKeg  I recommend you throw it out.  A lock that has failed you once may do it again.   WD40 is not a lubricant, its a water-displacer and a penetrating fluid.  As such it only lubricates for a short time.   If you do choose to keep the lock, lube it with chain oil, and don't leave it wet.  Try sticking a plastic bag over your lock if using it in the rain, and if it did get wet dry it inside that niight.

Comment: Also, locks are often lubricated with graphite or other specialist lubricants that may react badly to the WD40. The slight residue from the wd40 will also attract dust and grit, which are bad things to have inside a lock.